# Adding data to deep node in Plist with Python

Tags: python, xml, plist

I have a plist that I initially pull information from then need to write information to it. With xml.etree.ElementTree, i can access "WUT" but if i try to overwrite that with the number '1' or add another line with '2' after it using this:

```
ET.SubElement(plist[0][15][1][1][1][1][1][1][1], '1')
```

or with

```
plist[0][15][1][1][1][1][1][1][1].append('1')
```

I will get an index out of bounds error because obviously the node 1 doesnt exist yet.

I need to add to a specific node (and in most cases create that node). Below under the WUT I would like to add roughly 200 string children with random information (lets say 1-200 for now). How would I do this with either plistlib or xml.etree.ElementTree.

```
<key>Title</key>
<dict>
  <key>Set</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Notes</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Tester</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>13</key>
          <dict>
            <key>Param</key>
            <array>
              <string>WUT</string>
            </array>
          </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>82</key>
          <dict>
            <key>Param</key>
            <array>
              <string>WUT</string>
            </array>
          </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>64</key>
          <dict>
            <key>Param</key>
            <array>
              <string>WUT</string>
            </array>
          </dict>
        </dict>
```

and the result i would like to achieve is:

```
<key>Title</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Set</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Notes</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Tester</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>13</key>
              <dict>
                <key>Param</key>
                <array>
                  <string>1</string>
                  <string>2</string>
                  <string>3</string>
                  <string>4</string>
                  <string>5</string>
                  <string>6</string>
                  <string>7</string>
                </array>
              </dict>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>82</key>
              <dict>
                <key>Param</key>
                <array>
                  <string>WUT</string>
                </array>
              </dict>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>64</key>
              <dict>
                <key>Param</key>
                <array>
                  <string>WUT</string>
                </array>
              </dict>
            </dict>
```

*Edit these are the for loops i have tried to get into the right location. It seems that it only goes for the last one though meaning it would put my new data into "Writing" instead of "Notes".

```
for plist_title in tree.xpath('//dict[key="Notes"][1]')
    for plist_tester in plist_title.xpath('//dict[key="13"][1]')
        plist_tester.insert(1,myData)
```

and if i wanted it to get into writing i would do something similar:

```
for plist_title in tree.xpath('//dict[key="Writing"][1]')
    for plist_tester in plist_title.xpath('//dict[key="13"][1]')
        plist_tester.insert(1,myData)
```

Or a different tester level:

```
for plist_title in tree.xpath('//dict[key="Notes"][1]')
    for plist_tester in plist_title.xpath('//dict[key="82"][1]')
        plist_tester.insert(1,myData)
```

sadly they dont work though :(

Comment: You want to replace the first `WUT` with your array of string tags?

Comment: Yes basically, but in somecases will need to add the node because WUT wont exist.

Comment: Ok, so then you want to always add the array of strings to the first `Param` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with a bit of xpath magic:

```
from lxml import etree

from lxml.builder import E

plist = """
<root>
  <key>Title</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Set</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Notes</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Tester</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>13</key>
            <dict>
              <key>Param</key>
              <array>
                <string>WUT</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
          </dict>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</root>"""
```

This creates an lxml object (you can load it from a file too):

```
xml_data = etree.fromstring(plist)
```

Create candidate element array:

```
array = E('array')

for num in range(10):
    array.append(E.string(str(num)))
```

Here is what it looks like:

```
print(etree.tostring(array, pretty_print=True))
<array>
  <string>0</string>
  <string>1</string>
  <string>2</string>
  <string>3</string>
  <string>4</string>
  <string>5</string>
  <string>6</string>
  <string>7</string>
  <string>8</string>
  <string>9</string>
</array>
```

From the main plist, grab the interesting entry, in this case is the first array that contains `WUT`, remove it and append the tag you want:

```
for first_array_contains_wut in xml_data.xpath('//array[string="WUT"][1]'):
    parent_tag = first_array_contains_wut.getparent()
    parent_tag.remove(first_array_contains_wut)
    parent_tag.append(array)
```

And here is what the final version looks like after mangling:

```
print(etree.tostring(xml_data, pretty_print=True))
<root>
  <key>Title</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Set</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Notes</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Tester</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>13</key>
            <dict>
              <key>Param</key>
              <array><string>0</string><string>1</string><string>2</string><string>3</string><string>4</string><string>5</string><string>6</string><string>7</string><string>8</string><string>9</string></array></dict>
          </dict>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</root>
```

From the comments:

> If the key "Notes" could change around to "Writing" in the same plist, is there a way to use xpath to search for both "Writing" and the "13" key? If both Notes and writing had 13, there is no way i could be sure i have found it. I tried with 2x for loops, but i always end up with the second "13".

You can try a more explicit match, if this is what I understand your node to look like:

```
<root>
  <key>Title</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Set</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Notes</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Tester</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
            <key>13</key>
            <dict>
              <key>Param</key>
              <array>
                <string>WUT</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
          </dict>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>Writing</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Tester</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>13</key>
              <dict>
                <key>Param</key>
                <array>
                  <string>WUT2</string>
                </array>
              </dict>
            </dict>
          </array>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</root>
```

If I want to get 'WUT2' which is under the dict that has 'Writing', you can do:

```
In [26]: [x.text for x in xml_data.xpath('//dict[key/text()="Writing"]//string')]
Out[26]: ['WUT2']
```

However if you are after the second '13' key, then you can do something like:

```
In [35]: [x.text for x in xml_data.xpath('//dict[//key[text()="13"]][2]//string')]
Out[35]: ['WUT2']
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, appreciate all the effort you put in for the answer. One other question you may be able to help with. If the key "Notes" could change around to "Writing" in the same plist, is there a way to use xpath to search for both "Writing" and the "13" key? If both Notes and writing had 13, there is no way i could be sure i have found it. I tried with 2x for loops, but i always end up with the second "13".

Comment: Closer, but given the first xml i gave, there are also nodes 82 and 64, i may not know the order. So is there a way to index through and select the correct node using both what you provided in the first part searching for "Writing" and then the search for "13"? Added a comment for the for loops i tried so it may make it more clear.

Comment: @Dippy try `'//dict[key/text()="Writing"]/dict[//key[text()="13"]]'`

Comment: Thank again for all your help salparadise. Almost compelted everything, just need to figure out how these strings convert to search terms. I didnt find much in the documentation for lxml. Where did you learn these from?

Comment: @Dippy this is not exclusive to lxml, this is [xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), a fairly wide known standard for parsing xml. [Some examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)